# Making a jQuery field with autocomplete required

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Hi i have a problem with jQuery autcomplete, I have a field where users type in names and it's working great.

How do I make it **required**? I mean I want the user to have to add at least one user using the autocomplete field.

I also use the [white template label](http://revaxarts-themes.com/whitelabel/form.html)

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your using jquery u can use the required method http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required
and make the field required so that user inputs atleast one.

Answer (score -1):

If you happen to only need this functionality in modern browsers supporting HTML5. A simpler solution might be the new 'required' attribute: [W3Schools Required Attr](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)